# Getting a twitter timeline in a AS3 AIR app

Tags: android, actionscript-3, api, twitter

So I'm developing an Android app (in AS3 using Adobe AIR) that should list the timeline of a public twitter account. 
I have never had any experience with developing Apps that use internet requests and what not.

I also heard that twitter have recently changed their api.

Could any body help me? How do I get the timeline of a non-protected account in json or xml format? and how does authentication work in AS3?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/susisu/Twitter-for-AS3
Use that, works fine as far as I could test.

In case you need it, here is my implementation example, it may help a bit:

```
package com.company.social {

    import com.company.AppConst;
    import com.company.IDestroyable;
    import com.company.Main;
    import com.company.displayassets.WebViewCloseStripe;
    import com.company.events.TwitterControllerEvent;

    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.PNGEncoderOptions;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.LocationChangeEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
    import flash.filesystem.File;
    import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
    import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.media.StageWebView;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import flash.utils.clearInterval;
    import flash.utils.clearTimeout;
    import flash.utils.setInterval;
    import flash.utils.setTimeout;

    import isle.susisu.twitter.Twitter;
    import isle.susisu.twitter.TwitterRequest;
    import isle.susisu.twitter.TwitterTokenSet;
    import isle.susisu.twitter.events.TwitterErrorEvent;
    import isle.susisu.twitter.events.TwitterRequestEvent;

    public class TwitterController extends EventDispatcher implements IDestroyable {

        private var _destroyed:Boolean;
        private var _twitter:Twitter;
        private var _token:TwitterTokenSet;
        private var _twitterReq:TwitterRequest;
        private var _stage:Stage;
        private var _topStripe:WebViewCloseStripe;
        private var _webView:StageWebView;
        private var _pinExtractable:Boolean;
        private var _activity:String;
        private var _timeoutID:uint;
        private var _pinTimeoutID:uint;
        private static const ACTIVITY_LOGIN:String = "login";
        private static const ACTIVITY_TWEET:String = "tweet";
        private static const FILENAME:String = AppConst.TWITTER_FILE;
        private static const CONSUMER_KEY:String = AppConst.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY;
        private static const CONSUMER_SECRET:String = AppConst.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET;

        public function TwitterController(stage:Stage) {
            _stage = stage;
            init();
        }

        private function init():void {
            var complete:Function;

            checkForSettings();

            _activity = ACTIVITY_LOGIN;

            if (_token && _token.oauthToken.length) {
                trace("token");
                _twitter = new Twitter(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, _token.oauthToken, _token.oauthTokenSecret);
                _twitterReq = _twitter.account_verifyCredentials();
                complete = verifyCompleteHandler;
            } 
            else {
                trace("no token");
                _twitter = new Twitter(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
                _twitterReq = _twitter.oauth_requestToken();
                complete = tokenCompleteHandler;
            }

            setHandlersForRequest(complete);
            startTimeout();
        }

        private function startTimeout():void {
            trace("timeout start");
            clearTimeout(_timeoutID);
            _timeoutID = setTimeout(timeout, AppConst.TIMEOUT_TIME);
        }

        private function timeout():void {
            trace("timed out");
            clearTimeout(_timeoutID);
            if(_twitterReq) {
                _twitterReq.removeEventListener(TwitterRequestEvent.COMPLETE, tokenCompleteHandler);
                _twitterReq.removeEventListener(TwitterRequestEvent.COMPLETE, verifyCompleteHandler);
                _twitterReq.removeEventListener(TwitterRequestEvent.COMPLETE, pinRequestCompleteHandler);
                _twitterReq.removeEventListener(TwitterRequestEvent.COMPLETE, tweetCompleteHandler);

                _twitterReq.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
                _twitterReq.removeEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, errorHandler);
                _twitterReq.removeEventListener(TwitterErrorEvent.CLIENT_ERROR, errorHandler);
                _twitterReq.removeEventListener(TwitterErrorEvent.SERVER_ERROR, errorHandler);
            }
            dispatchEvent(new TwitterControllerEvent(TwitterControllerEvent.TIMEOUT));
        }

        private function stopTimeout():void {
            trace("timeout stop");
            clearTimeout(_timeoutID);
        }

        private function setHandlersForRequest(completeHandler:Function):void {
            trace("set");
            _twitterReq.addEventListener(TwitterRequestEvent.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            _twitterReq.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
            _twitterReq.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, errorHandler);
            _twitterReq.addEventListener(TwitterErrorEvent.CLIENT_ERROR, errorHandler);
            _twitterReq.addEventListener(TwitterErrorEvent.SERVER_ERROR, errorHandler);
        }

        private function removeHandlersForRequest(completeHandler:Function):void {
            trace("remove");
            _twitterReq.removeEventListener(TwitterRequestEvent.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            _twitterReq.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
            _twitterReq.removeEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, errorHandler);
            _twitterReq.removeEventListener(TwitterErrorEvent.CLIENT_ERROR, errorHandler);
            _twitterReq.removeEventListener(TwitterErrorEvent.SERVER_ERROR, errorHandler);
        }

        private function verifyCompleteHandler(e:TwitterRequestEvent):void {
            stopTimeout();
            removeHandlersForRequest(verifyCompleteHandler);
            dispatchEvent(new TwitterControllerEvent(TwitterControllerEvent.LOGIN_COMPLETE));
        }

        private function tokenCompleteHandler(e:TwitterRequestEvent):void {
            stopTimeout();
            removeHandlersForRequest(tokenCompleteHandler);

            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(_twitter.getOAuthAuthorizeURL());

            _topStripe = new WebViewCloseStripe();
            _topStripe.getCloseButton().addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeClickHandler);
            _stage.addChild(_topStripe);

            _webView = new StageWebView();
            _webView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE, locationChangeHandler);
            _webView.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, locationCompleteHandler);
            _webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, _topStripe.height, _stage.fullScreenWidth, _stage.fullScreenHeight - _topStripe.height);
            _webView.stage = _stage;
            _webView.assignFocus();
            _webView.loadURL(request.url);
        }

        private function locationChangeHandler(e:LocationChangeEvent):void {
            if (e.location.search("oauth_token") >= 0) {
                trace("loc change outath_token, returning: "+e.location);
                return;
            }
            else {
                _pinExtractable = true;
                trace("the magic should happen here: "+e.location);
            }
        }

        private function locationCompleteHandler(e:Event):void {
            if(_pinExtractable) {
                _webView.loadURL("javascript:document.title=document.documentElement.innerHTML;");
                _pinTimeoutID = setTimeout(extractPin, 16);
            }
        }

        private function extractPin():void {
            clearTimeout(_pinTimeoutID);
            var pin:String = String(_webView.title.split('<kbd aria-labelledby="code-desc"><code>')[1]).split("<")[0];
            trace("pin: "+pin);

            if (pin && pin.toString() != "undefined") {
                _webView.removeEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE, locationChangeHandler);
                _webView.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, locationCompleteHandler);
                _webView.dispose();
                _webView = null;

                _topStripe.getCloseButton().removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeClickHandler);
                _topStripe.destroy();
                _stage.removeChild(_topStripe);
                _topStripe = null;

                _twitterReq = _twitter.oauth_accessToken(pin);
                //request.addEventListener(TwitterRequestEvent.COMPLETE, pinRequestCompleteHandler);
                setHandlersForRequest(pinRequestCompleteHandler);
                startTimeout();
            }
            else {
                _pinTimeoutID = setTimeout(extractPin, 100);
            }
        }

        private function pinRequestCompleteHandler(e:Event):void {
            stopTimeout();
            removeHandlersForRequest(pinRequestCompleteHandler);

            _token = _twitter.accessTokenSet;

            saveSettings();

            dispatchEvent(new TwitterControllerEvent(TwitterControllerEvent.LOGIN_COMPLETE));

            trace("tokens: "+_token.oauthToken, _token.oauthTokenSecret);
        }

        private function checkForSettings():void {
            var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(FILENAME);
            var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();

            if(file.exists) {
                fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
                var data:Object = fileStream.readObject() as Object;
                fileStream.close();

                _token = new TwitterTokenSet(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, data.oauthToken, data.oauthTokenSecret);
            } 
            else {
                _token = null
            }
        }

        private function saveSettings():void {
            var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(FILENAME);
            var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
            fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
            fileStream.writeObject({oauthToken: _token.oauthToken, oauthTokenSecret: _token.oauthTokenSecret});
            fileStream.close();
        }

        private function errorHandler(e:Event):void {
            var request:TwitterRequest = e.currentTarget as TwitterRequest;

            request.removeEventListener(TwitterRequestEvent.COMPLETE, tokenCompleteHandler);
            request.removeEventListener(TwitterRequestEvent.COMPLETE, verifyCompleteHandler);
            request.removeEventListener(TwitterRequestEvent.COMPLETE, pinRequestCompleteHandler);
            request.removeEventListener(TwitterRequestEvent.COMPLETE, tweetCompleteHandler);

            request.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
            request.removeEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, errorHandler);
            request.removeEventListener(TwitterErrorEvent.CLIENT_ERROR, errorHandler);
            request.removeEventListener(TwitterErrorEvent.SERVER_ERROR, errorHandler);

            if(_activity == ACTIVITY_LOGIN) {
                dispatchEvent(new TwitterControllerEvent(TwitterControllerEvent.LOGIN_ERROR));
            }
            else if(_activity == ACTIVITY_TWEET) {
                dispatchEvent(new TwitterControllerEvent(TwitterControllerEvent.TWEET_ERROR));
            }

            if(e is TwitterErrorEvent) {
                trace(TwitterErrorEvent(e).statusCode.toString());
            }
        }

        private function tweetCompleteHandler(e:Event):void {
            trace("Tweet complete.");
            stopTimeout();
            removeHandlersForRequest(tweetCompleteHandler);
            dispatchEvent(new TwitterControllerEvent(TwitterControllerEvent.TWEET_COMPLETE));
        }

        private function closeClickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
            dispatchEvent(new TwitterControllerEvent(TwitterControllerEvent.CLOSE));
        }

        public function reset():void {
            _token = new TwitterTokenSet("", "", "", "");
            saveSettings();
            dispatchEvent(new TwitterControllerEvent(TwitterControllerEvent.RESET));
        }

        public function tweet(message:String):void {
            startTimeout();
            _activity = ACTIVITY_TWEET;
            _twitterReq = _twitter.statuses_update(message);
            setHandlersForRequest(tweetCompleteHandler);
        }

        public function tweetWithImage(message:String, imageData:BitmapData):void {
            startTimeout();
            var byteArray:ByteArray = imageData.encode(new Rectangle(0, 0, imageData.width, imageData.height), new PNGEncoderOptions()); 
            _twitterReq = _twitter.statuses_updateWithMedia(message, byteArray);
            setHandlersForRequest(tweetCompleteHandler);
        }

        public function destroy():void {
            if (_destroyed) return;

            clearTimeout(_pinTimeoutID);

            if(_twitterReq) {
                _twitterReq.removeEventListener(TwitterRequestEvent.COMPLETE, tokenCompleteHandler);
                _twitterReq.removeEventListener(TwitterRequestEvent.COMPLETE, verifyCompleteHandler);
                _twitterReq.removeEventListener(TwitterRequestEvent.COMPLETE, pinRequestCompleteHandler);
                _twitterReq.removeEventListener(TwitterRequestEvent.COMPLETE, tweetCompleteHandler);

                _twitterReq.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
                _twitterReq.removeEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, errorHandler);
                _twitterReq.removeEventListener(TwitterErrorEvent.CLIENT_ERROR, errorHandler);
                _twitterReq.removeEventListener(TwitterErrorEvent.SERVER_ERROR, errorHandler);
            }
            _twitterReq = null;

            if(_webView) {
                _webView.removeEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE, locationChangeHandler);
                _webView.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, locationCompleteHandler);
                _webView.dispose();
                _webView = null;
            }

            if(_topStripe) {
                _topStripe.getCloseButton().removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeClickHandler);
                _topStripe.destroy();
                _stage.removeChild(_topStripe);
                _topStripe = null;
            }

            _stage = null;
            if(_twitter) _twitter = null;
            if(_token) _token = null;

            _destroyed = true;
        }

        public function isDestroyed():Boolean {
            return _destroyed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to do this with HTMLLoader?

Comment: Where are the com.company assets?

Comment: @eco_bach Those assets do not have to interest you as they are just indirectly related (they don't really have much to do with the implementation of the library I mentioned) and they are rather self-explanatory (e.g.: WebViewCloseStripe.getCloseButton will obviously mean that it is a "close button sprite/mc"; AppConst.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY => I guess no need to comment about those, etc.)